# Convert ObjectResult<string> to List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass List as Json. How to create list of Member for AM_GAAM property?
Below is my controller's code. I am using stored procedure which returns only one column(AM_GAAM) with multiple rows.

> Controller

```
ObjectResult<string> obj;
obj = objConnection.ADDRESS_MASTER_Select_Distinct_Gaam(objIErrorCode);

if (Convert.ToInt32(objIErrorCode.Value) == 0)
{
     list = obj.Select(x => new Member
     {
         AM_GAAM = x.
     }).ToList();
}

return Json(new { Success = true, Message = list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: `AM_GAAM = x.AM_GAAM`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Not getting `x.AM_GAAM` because of string type of `ObjectResult<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ADDRESS_MASTER_Select_Distinct_Gaam` method returns a list of strings, you can do this

```
list=obj.Select(s=>new Member { AM_GAM_=x }).ToList();
```

But if your `ADDRESS_MASTER_Select_Distinct_Gaam` method is returning a list of some custom object where `AM_GAM` is a property of that custom class, you can do this

```
list=obj.Select(s=>new Member { AM_GAM_=x.AM_GAM }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot `list=obj.Select(s=>new Member { AM_GAM_=x }).ToList();` works

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous class

```
    var list;
    if (Convert.ToInt32(objIErrorCode.Value) == 0)
    {
        list = obj.Select(x => new
                {
                    AM_GAAM=x.ToString() //x.ToString() as list content string value
                });
    }


    return Json(new { Success = true, Message = list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```